# AWS RDS - Oracle - Grant permissions on sys

Tags: sql, oracle, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I'm trying to create a role and grant select permissions on sys.dba_objects.
This is my sql:

```
grant select on sys.dba_objects to my_role
grant select on sys.dba_objects to my_role;
```

On RDS I get the following error:
Error: ORA-01031: insufficient privileges

I saw that RDS has a dedicated stored procedure for granting permissions on sys. I tried:

```
call rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object('SYS.REGISTRY$HISTORY', 'my_role', 'select')
```

Error I get:

```
ORA-44003: invalid SQL name
ORA-06512: at "RDSADMIN.RDSADMIN_UTIL", line 248
ORA-44003: invalid SQL name
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Comment: Try to specify only the object. `call rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object('REGISTRY$HISTORY', 'MY_ROLE', 'SELECT')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I made it work:
1. Removed the sys. prefix like suggested above
2. Used uppercase

Example:

```
call rdsadmin.rdsadmin_util.grant_sys_object('DBA_OBJECTS', 'ASSESSMENT_ROLE', 'SELECT');
```

Comment: The role/username in upper case is very important - this did it for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know AWS RDS, but ORA-01031 sounds like a known restriction: privileges granted via roles won't work in PL/SQL procedures - you'll have to grant them directly to user.

Answer (score 0):

Try following...First you need to grant select to rdsadmin with grant option using SYS.

As SYS
grant select on DBA_objects to rdsadmin with grant option;

As rdsadmin

grant select on sys.dba_objects to my_role;

Comment: In second option kindly grant role SELECT ANY DICTIONARY to rdsadmin and after that execute following SQL statement.  As rdsadmin

grant select on sys.dba_objects to my_role;